# Angular Material Dialog Route leads to an infinite loop

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have to implement routes with Angular Material Dialogs, so that when I open a dialog, I also have the new URL. Since I didn't find any info in the libary docs, I came up with a workaround.

I created a DialogOpenerComponent that display nothing but opens a provided dialog:

```
@Component({
  template: ''
})
export class DialogOpenerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private dialog: MatDialog,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const {dialog, config} = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data;
    this.dialog.open(dialog, config).afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
    });
  }

}
```

I also have to provide routes:

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'flow',
            component: DialogOpenerComponent,
            data: {
              dialog: FlowComponent,
              config: {
                disableClose: true
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

And add router-outlet to the html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now it works like a charm! Until one moment...
The thing is that I have to add `router-outlet` into my flow dialog, so there are some kind of steps. After doing this I get into infinite loop.

Long story short, I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqedyw) so you can try it by yourself (**BEWARE: Clicking on the `Flow` hyperlink almost certainly will crash your browser!**).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a module and an router outlet in that module so that the module has its own router outlet which doesnt create this type of loop

Comment: I separated my components to modules but it has no effect :( 
Here is a new Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7btc5